# Finding endpoint (server) address when sending gRPC requests

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

Is there anyway to get the endpoint (server) address when sending gRPC requests in client? I have a client deployment talking to a server deployment in a kubernetes cluster through gRPC. Server deployment sits behind a clusterIP. I use clusterIP's name and port to establish a connection between my client and server. If I use more than one server (setting replicas to more than 1), is there any way to get targeted server address when sending gRPC requests at the client side? I want to chose an specific server, and I need its IP address. How can I find it at client side?

I think grpc/xds somehow does this by itself. However, It seems such information is hidden and there is no API to access it.

I am using golang.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/retry"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/resource"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

var kubeClient kubernetes.Interface
var kubeConfig *rest.Config

func init() {
    var err error

    kubeConfig, err = clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "/path/to/kubeconfig")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    kubeClient, err = kubernetes.NewForConfig(kubeConfig)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
}

func main() {
    r := manual.NewBuilderWithScheme("grpc")

    // get the IP and port of the pod for the gRPC service
    address, port, err := GetPodIPAndPort("grpc-service")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    // add the server address to the resolver
    r.InitialState(resolver.State{Addresses: []resolver.Address{
        {Addr: fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", address, port)},
    }})

    dialer := grpc.WithResolver(r).DialContext

    // use the dialer to create a connection to the server
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, "grpc://service-name", dialer)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    // do gRPC 
}

func GetPodIPAndPort(serviceName string) (string, int32, error) {
    // get the endpoints for the service
    endpoints, err := kubeClient.CoreV1().Endpoints("default").Get(context.TODO(), serviceName, v1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        if errors.IsNotFound(err) {
            return "", 0, fmt.Errorf("service not found: %s", serviceName)
        } else {
            return "", 0, err
        }
    }

    // get the IP and port of the first pod in the endpoints list
    if len(endpoints.Subsets) == 0 {
        return "", 0, fmt.Errorf("no pods found for service: %s", serviceName)
    }
    address := endpoints.Subsets[0].Addresses[0].IP
    port := endpoints.Subsets[0].Ports[0].Port

    return address, port, nil
}
```

For getting specific pod details we need to use kubernetes apis.